# MKMapView - to keep user at center and cover route drawn on mapview on the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, mkmapview, mkcoordinateregion

I'm trying to achieve as follows:

1. User should always be at the center of the screen on MKMapView.
2. Route is drawn on the map as user will move.
3. I know, i can calculate the region to cover all the tracked points on the screen.

But here's my problem:
When i calculate the MKCoordinateRegion and setting it, it just fits the region that is best fitting to the screen but as soon as i'm trying to place user at center, a part of the line drawn on the MKMapView goes out of the screen.

Can anybody face this problem or any suggestions to handle this specific case, any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So basically you want the userlocation to be in the center AND see the whole route at the same time ?

Comment: Yes, you're right. @Templar

Comment: I'd have an idea, I'm not sure it would work and sadly don't really have the time now to add a detailed answer. Basically, you should get the `boundingMapRect` of the polyline or overlay in MKMapRect coordinates. Since the userlocation will be the center, you should create another `MKMapRect` by reflecting this first one to the userlocation ( point symmetric ). Then get the minimum and maximums and create a bigger bounding `MKMapRect` and center to that.

Comment: I have posted my answer, the way i got it working very precise and effective. Please vote me if it helps anyone.

Answer (score 2):

I have accomplished it as follows:

1. Calculate the distance of farthest point from the user's current location (or any point you want to keep at the center).
2. Calculate the region, with your center point(user's current location in my case) and double the distance calculated above and make a region using te following code:

   **CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [myLocation coordinate];**

   **MKCoordinateRegion region =
         MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc, distance * 2, distance * 2);**
3. Set the region on the MapView and the trail will be shown inside the screen keeping user's location at the center.

Thanks.